# Selectoptions used in SelectCheckboxes shows the checkboxes in a single Row

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, selectoption

Selectoptions used in SelectCheckboxes shows the checkboxes in a single Row.
I need to show the checkboxes in different rows.
Ho can this be acheived.

My code is :

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
               <tr>
                <apex:selectCheckboxes borderVisible="true" value="{!countries}" styleClass="check">
                       <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
                </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                </tr>
                <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

My Controller is :
** Controller: **

```
public class sampleCon {

    public List<SelectOption> items{get;set;}
    public List<String> countries {get;set;}

    public PageReference test() {
        return null;
    }

    public sampleCon(){
        getItems();
    }

    public void getItems() {

        items= new List<SelectOption>();
        countries = new List<String>();
        /*
        options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
        */
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Case.Numbers__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = F.getPicklistValues();
        System.debug(P);
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : P)
          { 
             items.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 
          }

    }

         public List<String> getCountries() {
            return countries;
         }

         public void setCountries(List<String> countries) {
             this.countries = countries;
         }

    }
```

The output I get is :

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use layout="pageDirection" in selectCheckboxes for ex.

```
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
       <tr>
        <apex:selectCheckboxes borderVisible="true" value="{!countries}" styleClass="check" layout="pageDirection">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
        </tr>
        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Or in your 'check' class add "display: block;"

Comment: Thanks.It worked. Any Idea how to show the checkboxes in two columns.

Comment: For two columns you will need to use CSS. something like display:inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS :

```
.check tbody tr td{
    float: left! Important;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

This thing worked for me.